# Dealing with Quantifiers and Logic Connectives

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I was wanting to formally prove how 
∀x(P(x)∧Q(x)))≡∀xP(x)∧∀xQ(x). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What can you infer about $P$ and $Q$ from the fact that the conjunction of $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ is true over the entire domain(i.e. $\forall x$)?

Comment: I mean it seems obvious, but I was wanting a more formal proof. I did not know if there was one.

Comment: $\forall x(P(x)\wedge Q(x)) \implies \nexists x \text{ such that } P(x) \text{ is false. }$ Similarly for $Q$.
If you want even more rigor you can use proof by contradiction: assume that the right hand side is false and derive a contradiction.

Comment: So you imply that a certain values can not be false?

Comment: $\nexists$ is the symbol for "does not exist". I mean to say there is **no** $x$ for which $P(x)$ is false; which is the same as saying $P(x)$ is true for all $x$.

Comment: @Akay Proof by contradiction is not necessary. There's a straightforward constructive proof given suitable [rules for manipulating universal quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#Rules_of_inference). Basically, you instantiate one side to an arbitrary element of the domain (i.e. you introduce a fresh constant), do some very basic propositional reasoning, and then apply universal generalization to get the result which will be valid since it will still be in terms of the arbitrary element.

Comment: Could you please show this. I am aware of how to use universal generalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use formal semantics to prove this. So, let's first define what it means for two statements $\phi$ and $\psi$ to be equivalent: it means that for every interpretation (or structure) $I$: $I$ sets $\phi$ to true (we write this as $I \vDash \phi$) if and only if $I$ sets $\psi$ to true ($I \vDash \psi$).

In this case we are dealing with some universals, and the formal semantics for the universal is as follows:

$I \vDash \forall x \phi(x)$ iff for any object $d$ in the domain of $I$: $I[c/d] \vDash \phi(c)$ where $c$ is a new constant that $I[c/d]$ interprets as $d$. (that is: $c$ does not occur in the original language, and so is not interpreted by $I$, but $I[c/d]$ extends $I$ by interpreting $c$ as object $d$).  This is really just a very technical way of saying: $I$ sets $\forall x \phi(x)$ to True iff $\phi$ holds for every objects in the domain. E.g.: $\forall x P(x)$ iff all objects in the domain have the property that $I$ interprets the predicate symbol $P$ as.

OK, so now let's look at your specific case. We have for any interpretation $I$:

$I \vDash \forall x (P(x) \land Q(x))$ iff (semantics $\forall$)

$I[c/d] \vDash P(c) \land Q(c)$ for every $d \in I$ iff (semantics $\land$)

$I[c/d] \vDash P(c)$ and $I[c/d] \vDash Q(c)$ for every $d \in I$ iff (semantics $\forall$)

$I \vDash \forall x P(x)$ and $I \vDash \forall x Q(x)$ iff (semantics $\land$)

$I \vDash \forall x P(x) \land \forall x Q(x)$

So, since we have shown that for any interpretation $I$:

$I \vDash \forall (P(x) \land Q(x))$ iff $I \vDash \forall x P(x) \land \forall x Q(x)$

we have that

$\forall x (P(x) \land Q(x)) \equiv \forall x \ P(x) \land \forall x \ Q(x)$

Alternatively, we can try to show the equivalence using a (sound) proof system. There are many proof systems though, so if you need to use a particular one, you may want to let us know your rules, or try to transform the following formal proof into one that your system is happy with:

[image]

Comment: I am surprised you didn't explain it three different ways ;) Nice answer!! Very helpful!

Comment: @W.G. Ha! There actually are a few more ways :)

Comment: I posted one more question if you want to look at it I would appreciate it <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240987/biconditional-introduction>. If not, thank you for the help!