# Biconditional Introduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I recently asked a question dealing with universal quantifers [Dealing with Quantifiers and Logic Connectives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238741/dealing-with-quantifiers-and-logic-connectives/2239179?noredirect=1#comment4605567_2239179). I was looking at the definition of biconditional introduction which is the following:

$$\def\getsto{\gets\!\!\!\!\to} {A\to B, B\to A}~\vdash~B\getsto A$$

How can we deduce that $∀x~(P(x)∧Q(x))\to(∀x~P(x)∧∀x~Q(x))$ for a condition concerning the answer for [Dealing with Quantifiers and Logic Connectives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238741/dealing-with-quantifiers-and-logic-connectives/2239179?noredirect=1#comment4605567_2239179) for the 
**last step**? Is that because in the steps $∀x~(P(x)∧Q(x))$ appears above $(∀x~P(x)∧∀x~Q(x))$? This was the only step I was confused on using a sound proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah!  You simply have a different rule for biconditional Introduction than that was used in that proof. There are many different proof systems with different sets of rules, so that is what is going on here: your rule for introducing a boconditional is different from the one defined in the proof system used in the linked proof.

In that proof, the biconditional Introduction rule says that if you have two subproofs, where in the one you derive the right side from the left side, and in the other you derive the left side from the right side, then you can immediately assert the biconditional by pointing to those two subproofs.

Your rule works differently: it is looking for two conditionals. Now, if you have conditional introduction that allows you to derive a conditional from a subproof, then you would just need to do two more steps:

Derive $\forall x (P(x) \land Q(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x \ P(x) \land \forall x \ Q(x))$ from the first subproof (so do this between lines 9 and 10) and derive $(\forall x \ P(x) \land \forall x \ Q(x)) \rightarrow \forall x (P(x) \land Q(x))$ from the second subproof, and now you can use your biconditional introduction rule to derive the biconditional from those two conditionals.

Comment: So would I use conditional introduction <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference> to get to that point between lines 9 and 10? I have not used a syntactic consequence in that way. I am stuck between lines 9 and 10 to get an implication like that.

Comment: I get it! I appreciate your help!

Comment: @W.G. Great! Glad I could help!